# SQL Query question (count dates for each month)

Tags: sql

Hope you can help me with the following, i have the following view availble:
DD/MM/YYYY

```
ENTITY | StartDate  | EndDate    | CodeA | CodeB | Revenue | Currency
AZERT  | 01/01/2011 | 02/01/2011 | SU    | BOLD  | 100     | EUR
AZERT  | 28/01/2011 | 02/02/2011 | SU    | BOLD  | 500     | EUR
```

Can someone help with a query to pull the data so that I get the following summed?

```
ENTITY | YYYY.MM | CodeA | CodeB | DAYS | TIMES | Revenue | Currency
AZERT  | 2011.01 | SU    | BOD   | 5    | 2     | 500     | EUR
AZERT  | 2011.02 | SU    | BOD   | 1    | 0     | 100     | EUR
```

Where YYYY.MM is created depending on the difference between Sdate and EDate. 
And DAYS is the variance between the start and end day in the right month
And TIMES is the number of times that the StartDate occurs in that month
Revenue splitted depening how many days there are.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the database that you are using when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Why is Revenue `500` for `2011.01` and `100` for `2011.02` in the result set? Is it calculated somehow or just pulled from the original data (in which case you've probably mixed them up)? Also, can the range span more than 2 months, like `28/01/2011..05/03/2011`? If so, should *all* the months in the range be taken into account or just the starting and ending ones? And how should Revenue be calculated in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, would this work?

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(dd, -DAY(EndDate + 1,EndDate))  -- Get first day of month for EndDate
    ,CodeA
    ,CodeB
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate, EndDate)) AS 'DAYS'
FROM
    TABLE1
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(dd, -DAY(EndDate + 1,EndDate))  
    ,CodeA
    ,CodeB
```